# System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException project settings

Tags: c#, configuration, settings

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in
>   System.Configuration.dll
>
> Additional information: Configuration system failed to initialize

Happens at:

```
return ((bool)(this["StartupCheckbox"]));
```

This error is showing when I try to run my project. 
When I check the project settings the settings are there.

```
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.0
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace StartupApp.Properties {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "12.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("False")]
        public bool StartupCheckbox {
            get {
                return ((bool)(this["StartupCheckbox"]));
            }
            set {
                this["StartupCheckbox"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("0")]
        public int delayBetweenProgramCheckingNumeric {
            get {
                return ((int)(this["delayBetweenProgramCheckingNumeric"]));
            }
            set {
                this["delayBetweenProgramCheckingNumeric"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
        public string dependencies {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["dependencies"]));
            }
            set {
                this["dependencies"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
This only happens when I move my project location?